# Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: In Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

In my `SearchFragment.kt` I have:

```
private lateinit var userDb: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var users: MutableList<User>
private lateinit var adapter: UsersAdapters

fun getUsers() {
    users = mutableListOf()
    adapter = UsersAdapters(this, users)

    userDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val userReference = userDb.collection("users")
    userReference.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null || snapshot == null) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Somethings Wrong", exception)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        val userList = snapshot.toObjects(User::class.java)
        for (user in userList) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Document ${user.username}")
        }
    }
}
```

Which gets called in in `onViewCreated`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    getUsers()
}
```

My `UserAdapter.kt` look like:

```
package com.example.myapp

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_user.view.*

import com.example.myapp.models.User


class UsersAdapters (val context: Context, val users: List<User>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapters.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = users.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(users[position])
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(user: User) {
        itemView.etUsername.text = user?.username
        Glide.with(context).load(user.profileURL).into(itemView.profileImage)
    }
}
}
```

In `SearchFragment.kt` on the following line:

```
adapter = UsersAdapters(this, users)
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
SearchFragment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
adapter = UsersAdapters(requireActivity(), users)
```

Comment: @GurmukhSingh: If this solves your problem, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer once you're able to. (Assuming, of course, it's the most useful of the solutions offered.)

Comment: It is not a matter of just a working solution. I voted it down. That is not the right solution even if it works.  See the details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not pass the context to the adapter. Remove it, you don't need it.
2. When inflating your view, use `parent.context` instead of the outer context. you can also inline that return statement, like.

   return LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false)
3. You are using Glide, within your ViewHolder class,

replace

```
Glide.with(context).load(user.profileURL).into(itemView.profileImage)
```

with

```
Glide.with(itemView).load(user.profileURL).into(itemView.profileImage)
```

Glide will take the view as a parameter. That works and it is the right way to write your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
class ModeradorFragment: Fragment() {
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    Log.d(Constraints.TAG, "onAttach")
    super.onAttach(context)
}
```

I put the on attach at the beginning of the class
then use it in my linear layout

```
val layoutManager1 = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
val adapterpreg = PreguntasAdapter(this@ModeradorFragment, data)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).